# Rotating object around point based on mouse movement including diagonals

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```c#
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    
    if( selectedObjs.Count==0&&Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,100, 1 << 9))
        {
            currentPos = hit.point;
        }
    }

    if (mouseClickMode !=3 && mouseClickMode != 4 && !uiMenu_on 
        && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        float rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float rotY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        if (selectedObjs.Count > 0)
            currentPos = objectManager.ReturnPos(selectedObjs[0]);
                    
        transform.RotateAround(currentPos, Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime *450* rotX);
        transform.RotateAround(currentPos, Vector3.right, Time.deltaTime*450 * rotY);

   
    }
```

This rotation is rotating on the x axis and then on the y axis.

But when the mouse is moved diagonally, the axis is not a diagonal one. How can I have the object rotate around point on a diagonal axis when the mouse is moved diagonally?

Comment: Please don't use `Camera.main` in `Update` - you should use it infrequently or preferably once in `Start` or `Awake` and cache the result. [See here for more information](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHAjHEx0a0Y

Comment: I am now using a method of rotating the camera around the position taken with the mouse if there is no object clicked with the camera, but that method is not exactly correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the mouse's direction in world space using the camera's `transform.TransformDirection`. (note NO negative on `float rotY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");`)

Use cross product between the mouse's world direction and the camera's forward to determine the axis you're interested in rotating around.

Rotate based on the magnitude of the mouse's movement.

Altogether:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 currentPos;
    Camera mainCam;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        mainCam = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = mainCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                currentPos = hit.point;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            float rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            float rotY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

            Vector3 mouseMove = new Vector3(rotX, rotY, 0f);
            Vector3 mouseWorldDirection = mainCam.transform.TransformDirection(
                    mouseMove);
            Vector3 rotAxis = Vector3.Cross(mouseWorldDirection, 
                    mainCam.transform.forward);

            transform.RotateAround(currentPos, rotAxis, Time.deltaTime * 450f 
                    * mouseMove.magnitude);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: e.g.]

In your code, it might look like this:

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
if( selectedObjs.Count==0&&Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,100, 1 << 9))
    {
        currentPos = hit.point;
    }
}

if (mouseClickMode !=3 && mouseClickMode != 4 && !uiMenu_on 
    && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    float rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float rotY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    if (selectedObjs.Count > 0)
        currentPos = objectManager.ReturnPos(selectedObjs[0]);
                
    Vector3 mouseMove = new Vector3(rotX, rotY, 0f);
    Vector3 mouseWorldDirection = mainCam.transform.TransformDirection(mouseMove);
    Vector3 rotAxis = Vector3.Cross(mouseWorldDirection, mainCam.transform.forward);

    transform.RotateAround(currentPos, rotAxis, Time.deltaTime * 450f 
            * mouseMove.magnitude);
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between camera.transform.Lookat(mouseposition) and camera.transform.TransformDirection(mouseMove)  mouseMove is this page camera move Mouseposition is input.Mouse x,y

Comment: @KImJUngsilver `camera.transform.TransformDirection` takes a local space direction `mouseMove` and returns the world space direction `mouseWorldDirection`. For example, if `mouseMove` is `Vector3.right` and `camera.transform.right` is `Vector3.forward` then `mouseWorldDirection` will be `Vector3.forward`.  `LookAt` will change the rotation of `camera` but that's not enough because we want to change the position also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```c#
transform.RotateAround(currentPos, Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime *450* rotX);
transform.RotateAround(currentPos, Vector3.right, Time.deltaTime*450 * rotY);
```

Try:

```c#
transform.RotateAround(currentPos, new Vector3(rotY, rotX, 0), Time.deltaTime * 450);
```

So that you're not rotating on the 2 axis seperately.

---

Or if don't want only diagonal movement:

```c#
    float diagonalDeadzone = 0.2f;
    float rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float rotY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    if (selectedObjs.Count > 0)
        currentPos = objectManager.ReturnPos(selectedObjs[0]);
    if (rotX < diagonalDeadzone && rotX > -diagonalDeadzone)
    {
        transform.RotateAround(currentPos, Vector3.up * rotX, Time.deltaTime * 450);
    }
    else if (rotY < diagonalDeadzone && rotY > -diagonalDeadzone)
    {
        transform.RotateAround(currentPos, Vector3.right * rotY, Time.deltaTime * 450);
    }
```

Comment: You put it in place of your code instead of that code
The rotation up and down didn't work at all
I think I should make this drive only when the axis of rotation is diagonal only when it is a perfect diagonal.

Comment: @KImJUngsilver the answer is meant to be `transform.RotateAround(currentPos, new Vector3(rotY, rotX, 0), Time.deltaTime * 450);`. How does that work?

Comment: @Ruzihm that is work but It moves differently from the previously used up and down rotation. So I do this
Only try to use it when it is on the diagonal of the mouse

Comment: @DotCS thank you I will go home and make the video and upload it.