# what is the blender camera rotating shaft?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making blender's camera rotation with Unity, but it's not easy
The camera rotation method I was doing was rotation through the external product of the camera and mouse pointer, but this is not as smooth as Blender.

Refer to [Rotating object around point based on mouse movement including diagonals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63275926/rotating-object-around-point-based-on-mouse-movement-including-diagonals)

i use that but it was not blender's rotating
i think blenders rotating shaft is different

[Blender's rotating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4fhW.gif)

how to implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword you need here is "orbiting camera". There should be some code for that out on the web and if you have a few spare bucks, there is a good looking implementation available as an asset: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/camera/camera-orbit-44146